# Gihub on Mac using oath2

Tags: command-line, git

After a pause of 2 years from macOS I bought a new laptop to find this problem:

I cannot pull/push to my repositories using a user/password. The new approach is through oath2. At this point, I am able to push/pull from my own repositories but I cannot do that for the parent of a forked repo or pull from my own organization. The new approach is:

`git clone https://<token>@github.com/owner/repo.git`

My question is: how to apply this approach to pull from a repo that I have in my organization or a parent repo?

Comment: It not clear what the problem is. Is there an error message that your getting?  What version of macOS are you using?  Can you please [edit] your post with some clarifying details?

Comment: I've written an answer to your question but this is not an Apple related issue based on what you've provided and might be better suited for regular Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

Github supports multiple formats for authentication, but username & password is not one of them.

- You can generate a personal access token in the Developer settings and use that in place of a password when cloning

  - You can use the `gh` command line tool to automate creation of the access token
- You can generate an SSH key and provide Github your public key in your SSH settings on Github.com

Note that if you are a member of an organization, you may have to authorize the OAuth Key or SSH Key for access to your org

[Github Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github#authenticating-with-the-command-line)